# Sync commit history of master and develop

Tags: git, github

I am using master as a production branch which is fetched nightly onto many servers as read only. Master should never be ahead of develop because I only push to develop. When develop is stable, I want to fast forward master to match it.

I am currently doing this with:
git checkout master
git pull origin develop
git push origin +master

This works for me and syncs everything nicely, but it feels a bit wrong. There is another dev on my team that likes to just merge develop into master like a normal person. However, merging creates a merge git which makes master 1 commit ahead of develop. These build up over time and makes the git history unclean and annoying to look at. If I do my branch cloning hack, those merge commits disappear on remote but remain on my team's local branch.

I tried git rebase and git merge --ff, but those change hashes which still show as uneven.

Summary: How do I cleanly fast forward master to be perfectly even with develop? Or am I just not using git the way it is meant to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally your flow seems to be right.
But since it is an absolute requirement to do a fast-forward only, you should pass `--ff-only` to enforce it.

```
git checkout master 
git fetch origin
git merge --ff-only origin/develop
git push origin master
```

`--ff` is not needed, since fast-forward is a default behavior.

> I tried git rebase and git merge --ff, but those change hashes which
>   still show as uneven.

Fast-forward merge [by definition](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge) never creates merge commit, but only updates the  branch pointer:

> --ff When the merge resolves as a fast-forward, only update the branch pointer, without creating a merge commit. This is the default
>   behavior.